# outdoor preservative

Tags: outdoor

A neighbor has outdoor sculpture (an owl) carved from a tree trunk left at just the right height for the purpose when the tree was felled. It's several years old and well maintained. It's time to apply a next coat of preservative. We don't know what preservative  was used last time.

Recommendations, please.

Comment: Have you tried a search using the word preservative? It brings up many of the past threads with relevant info.

Comment: @Graphus No, I should have. I did look for a preservative tag. I thought the two word combination in the title would trigger suggested answers. Search now found https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/ideal-outdoor-preservative-for-a-wooden-ornament which will probably do. More specific help with this still-on-the-trunk object would be helpful but probably doesn't matter much.

Comment: Yeah standing dead trees or sawn lumber makes pretty much no difference as far as this goes.

Comment: @Graphus Thanks, Post as an answer and I'll accept it so the question doesn't stay on the unanswered queue. Or I can just delete.

Comment: You can self-Answer if you like, that way the Q doesn't go unanswered *and* you get a badge :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Graphus (see comments) I found my answer on this site at [Ideal outdoor preservative for a wooden ornament](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/ideal-outdoor-preservative-for-a-wooden-ornament)

Answering here so the question comes off the unanswered queue and no longer attracts attention.